# A bounded monotonic function on an closed interval has Fourier coefficient decaying in O(1/|n|)

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, riemann-sum

On interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, $|f|\leq B$ for $B\geq 0$, and $f$ is assumed to be monotonically increasing.

We want to prove that $\hat f(n)=O(1/|n|)$ for $|n|$ large enough, that is for all large $|n|$,  $|\hat f(n)|\leq C/|n|$ for some $C>0$.

My thought:

$f$ is Riemann integrable, so once we proved the Riemann sum of $2\pi g(\phi)=(f(\phi)e^{-in\phi})$  on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is bounded by $C/|n|$ for $|n|$ large, we are done.

My problem:

I failed to bounded the Riemann sum of $f(\phi)e^{-in\phi}$ with some constant divided by $|n|$. Hence, I can only prove that $\hat f(n)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical argument ends up reproving the integration-by-parts formula in some limited form. For the Riemann-Stieljes integral, $\int_{a}^{b}f\,dg$ exists iff $\int_{a}^{b}g\,df$ exists, and, in that case,
$$
              \left.\int_{a}^{b}f\,dg = fg\right|_{a}^{b}-\int_{a}^{b}g\,df.
$$
These integrals exist if $f$ is monotone and $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, which applies to this case. Hence,
$$
\begin{align}
     \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-inx}f(x)\,dx & = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\frac{d}{dx}\frac{e^{-inx}}{-in}\,dx \\
   & = \frac{1}{-in}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)d(e^{-inx})\\
   & = \left.\frac{e^{-inx}}{-in}f(x)\right|_{x=-\pi}^{\pi}-\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{-inx}}{-in}df(x) \\
   & = -\frac{f(\pi)-f(-\pi)}{in}+\frac{1}{in}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-inx}df(x).
\end{align}
$$
Because $f$ is non-decreasing, '$df$' is non-negative and $|e^{-inx}|=1$ gives
$$
      |\hat{f}(n)| \le \frac{f(\pi)-f(-\pi)}{n}+\frac{1}{n}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}df(x) \\
                     = \frac{2(f(\pi)-f(-\pi))}{n}.
$$

Comment: But $f$ is not necessarily differentiable. Can we use $df(x)$? I searched for the Riemann-Stieljes integral, but I did not see (or I just did not realize) the use of non-diffrentiable founction in this case.

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of using the Riemann-Stieljes integral. If $g$ is continuous and $f$ is of bounded variation, then $\int_{a}^{b}g df$ and $\int_{a}^{b}fdg$ exist and they are related by $\int_{a}^{b}gdf = gf|_{a}^{b}-\int_{a}^{b}fdg$. The integral is defined as $\lim_{\|\mathcal{P}\|\rightarrow 0}\sum_{\mathcal{P}}g(t_{j}^{\star})\{f(t_{j})-f(t_{j-1})\}$. Monotone functions are of bounded variation on $[a,b]$; in fact every real function of bounded variation is the difference of two non-decreasing functions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Answer (score 4):

**Hints**:

WLOG, we assume $f$ be increasing, bounded by $M$.

1. First check Fourier series for $\chi_{[a,b]}$ satisfies $O(1/|n|)$.
2. Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^N \alpha_k\chi_{[a_k,a_{k+1}]}(x)$$ with $-\pi=a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_N<a_{N+1}=\pi$, and $-M\leq\alpha_1<\alpha_2<\cdots<\alpha_N\leq M$ has Fourier coefficient
   $$\sum_{k=1}^N \alpha_k\frac{e^{-inx_{k}}-e^{-inx_{k+1}}}{in}=\frac{\alpha_1 e^{-inx_1}-\alpha_{N} e^{-inx_{N+1}}+\sum_{k=2}^{N-1} (\alpha_{k+1}-\alpha_{k})e^{-inx_{k+1}}}{in}$$
   Hence $$|\sum_{k=1}^N \alpha_k\frac{e^{-inx_{k}}-e^{-inx_{k+1}}}{in}|=|\frac{\alpha_1 e^{-inx_1}-\alpha_{N} e^{-inx_{N+1}}+\sum_{k=2}^{N-1} (\alpha_{k+1}-\alpha_{k})e^{-inx_{k+1}}}{in}|\\ \leq \frac{|\alpha_1 e^{-inx_1}-\alpha_{N} e^{-inx_{N+1}}|+|\sum_{k=2}^{N-1} (\alpha_{k+1}-\alpha_{k})e^{-inx_{k+1}}|}{|n|}\\=\frac{-\alpha_1 +\alpha_{N} +\sum_{k=2}^{N-1} (\alpha_{k+1}-\alpha_{k})}{|n|}\leq \frac{4M}{|n|}$$

wihci is $O(1/|n|)$ uniformly in $N$.

3. Finally show $f$ can be approximated by this type of function due to Riemann integrability and monotonicity.

Comment: That's the hint I found in my textbook, and I believe we have the same textbook. I failed to follow its path...

Comment: By the way, I kind think it's too indirect to be considered a good way to go.

Comment: @MFSO_Zhou Which part you don't understand? I am not sure whether there is any quicker step for this problem. But I think the idea of this method is quit useful. If you want to prove $f$ has some property. first prove $g$ has some properties for some simpler $g$ say continuous function or step function, then approximate $f$ by $g$.

Comment: I just failed to have $\sum \alpha_{k+1}-\alpha_{k}$ bounded by $2M$.

Comment: @MFSO_Zhou I have added more details in step2. For step 3, just notice $f$ can be approximated by step functions by Darboux lower sum, which is of the form in step 2.

Comment: Shouldn't be bounded by $3M/|n|$? $\alpha_{N}-\alpha_{1}\leq 2M$ and $\sum_{k=2}^{N-1}(\alpha_{k+1}-\alpha_{k})=\alpha_{N}-\alpha_{2}\leq M$

Comment: @MFSO_Zhou Suppose by $4M$, I just modified it.

Comment: Even though once greater than $3M$ will do, the hint it gives kinda misled me though, since $\sum \alpha_{k+1}-\alpha_{k}$ is actually bounded by $M$, am I correct?

Comment: I feel grateful to you. A lot thanks.

Comment: @MFSO_Zhou I am glad it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Let say $$a_n=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{inx}dx$$
and we want to prove that $a_n\in O(\frac{1}{n})$.

Consider

$$na_n=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{inx}ndx=\int_{-n\pi}^{n\pi}f(\frac{x}{n})e^{ix}dx$$

$$\operatorname{Im}(na_n)=\int_{-n\pi}^{(-n+1)\pi}f(\frac{x}{n})\sin xdx+\int_{(-n+1)\pi}^{(-n+2)\pi}f(\frac{x}{n})\sin xdx+\dots+\int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi}f(\frac{x}{n})\sin xdx$$
$$=f(\frac{x_1}{n})\int_{-n\pi}^{(-n+1)\pi}\sin xdx+f(\frac{x_2}{n})\int_{(-n+1)\pi}^{(-n+2)\pi}\sin xdx+\dots+f(\frac{x_{2n}}{n})\int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi}\sin xdx$$
$$=(-1)^{n}\left[f(\frac{x_1}{n})-f(\frac{x_2}{n})+f(\frac{x_3}{n})-\dots-f(\frac{x_{2n}}{n})\right]$$
since $f$ is monotonically increasing we have
$$f(-\pi)-f(\pi)\le f(\frac{x_1}{n})-f(\frac{x_{2n}}{n})\le f(\frac{x_1}{n})-f(\frac{x_2}{n})+f(\frac{x_3}{n})-\dots-f(\frac{x_{2n}}{n})\le 0$$
therefore
$$|\operatorname{Im(na_n)}|\le f(\pi)-f(-\pi)$$

Similarly we can prove that $|\operatorname{Re}(na_n)|$ is bounded. Therefore $|na_n|$ is bounded, or $a_n\in O(\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: Would you please define $x_{i}/n$ you use?

Comment: I use the mean value theorem to evaluate the integral over a interval in which $\sin$ does not change sign. $x_i$ is the corresponding mean point in the interval $[(-n+i-1)\pi;(-n+i)\pi]$